# Qt get substring of a large QString that fits inside fixed QRect

Tags: qt, text, word-wrap

I have a large string, a fixed font and a fixed rectangle to draw that string into.

- If the string doesn't fit, I would like to know the length of substring that does fit into that rectangle
- if the string does fit, then I would like to know bounding rectangle height

I searched the web all day and found nothing.

Comment: `QFontMetrics::boundingRect` and heuristics?

Comment: I can create a binary search like algorithm, to find substring that fits using boundingRect(), but I assume that it could be very inefficient.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the [QFontMetrics](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qfontmetrics.html) class and its boundingRect class, get the rect used by the string provided

```
// assumes myFont has been instantiated
QFontMetrics fm(myFont);
QRect bounds = fm.boundingRect("Some text here");
```

Compare the size of bounds with the area with which to test if the string will fit.

> If the string doesn't fit, I would like to know the length of substring that does fit into that rectangle

If the bounds of the returned rect from boundingRect is too large, recursively remove characters until the width fits into your target rect.

```
bool bFits = false;
QString str = "String to test boundary";
QFontMetrics fm(myFont);
QRect bounds;
do
{    
    bounds = fm.boundingRect(str);
    // Assume testBoundary is the defined QRect of the area to hold the text
    if(!testBoundary.contains(bounds) && (!str.isEmpty()) )
         str.chop(1);
    else
        bFits = true;
}while(!bFits);
```

> if the string does fit, then I would like to know bounding rectangle height

This is simply the height of the returned rect from the call to boundingRect.

```
int height = bounds.height();
```

Comment: The problem is that I know that the string is not fitting. I would like to know max length substring that does fit.

Comment: As the updated answer states, in a loop remove characters of the string until it fits.

Comment: It has occured to me also, but I assume removing characters/words/lines would be pretty inefficient, as the algorithm is always calculating bounding rectangle of the same string. It there some other way to calculate this?

Comment: Unless the string is incredibly long, the performance is negligible. You shouldn't really worry too much about performance, until you notice such an issue, at which point you can profile your app and optimise where required. Of-course, being mindful of good programming is not a bad thing, but shouldn't be an issue here.

Comment: It might be a good idea to draw the result of this calculations to a pixmap of the rect's size. In future paint events you only need to paint that pixmap using QPainter::drawPixmap. only redraw that pixmap if the string or the rect size change. This can speed up the drawing a big deal .. means put the calculations out of the paintEvent.

Comment: Thanks a lot for a detailed answer

Comment: Sure, I just want to see if someone wants to post another answer.

Comment: A simple optimization would be doing "binary search" to find the maximum length instead of the chop(1).

Answer (score 1):

I am posting my own binary search algorithm. `Batman` pointed out in the right direction, thanks!

BTW you can use `QFontMetrics` instead of `QPainter` if you want.

```
int FontUtils::FittingLength(const QString& s, QPainter &p, const QRectF& rect,
                             int flags/* = Qt::AlignLeft | Qt::AlignTop | Qt::TextWordWrap*/)
{
    QRectF r = p.boundingRect(rect, flags, s);
    if (r.height() <= rect.height()) // String fits rect.
        return s.length();

    // Apply binary search.
    QString sub;
    int left = 0, right = s.length()-1;
    do
    {
        int pivot = (left + right)>>1; // Middle point.
        sub = s.mid(0, pivot+1);
        r = p.boundingRect(rect, flags, sub);

        if (r.height() > rect.height()) // Doesn't fit.
            right = pivot-1;
        else
            left = pivot+1;
    } while (left < right);

    left++; // Length of string is one char more.

    // Remove trailing word if it doesn't fit.
    if  ( !s.at(left).isSpace() && !s.at(left+1).isSpace() )
    {
        while ( (--left > 0) && !sub.at(left).isSpace() );
        left++;
    }

    return left;
}
```